Problem placing information at the bottom of the first page
I am working on the development of template and I would like to have something similar like this:

I'm working in twocolumn document and I tried to replicate it in \fancyfoot[L]{} (only for the first page) but, the margin is not enough for the information and I have not been able to implement something that automatically adjusts.
I'll leave an example of the document class and the main.tex
Document class example code
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{example}[2024/03/28 Rho LaTeX class]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{extarticle}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}

%---------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{url}

%---------------------------------------------

\usepackage[left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.75cm]{geometry}

%---------------------------------------------

\newcommand\correspondingauthor[2][]{
  \gdef\@corres{\textsuperscript{#1}\fontsize{6.5}{9}\selectfont#2}
}
\newcommand{\footerfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\institution}[1]{\def\@institution{#1}}
\newcommand{\etal}[1]{\def\@etal{#1}}
\newcommand{\course}[1]{\def\@course{#1}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\def\@doi{#1}}
\newcommand{\footitle}[1]{\def\@footitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\footinfo}[1]{\def\@footinfo{#1}}

%---------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
    \fancyhead[R]{}
    \fancyhead[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{}
    \fancyfoot[R]{
        \vspace{-5pt}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
            \footnotesize
            \vskip1.5pt
            \@corres\par
            \@doi\par
            \@footinfo\par
        \end{minipage}
    }
        \vskip-25pt
}

% Header
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily\footnotesize{\itshape\@title}\hspace{10pt}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\footnotesize{\bfseries\thepage}\hspace{10pt}{\itshape\@title}}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}

% Footer
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%

\fancyfoot[RO]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@institution\hspace{10pt}{\bfseries\@date}\hspace{10pt}\@footitle}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@etal}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@etal}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@course}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % No footer rule

Example of the main.tex
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twoside]{example}

%---------------------------------------------

\title{Example}
\author{Author 1}
\date{April 2024}

%---------------------------------------------
% Using the commands
%---------------------------------------------

\correspondingauthor[$\ast$]{Corresponding author at: This is an example of how you can customize this part of the article. Please, provide the corresponding author information and publisher here. \textit{E-mail address:} example@organization.com.}

\footinfo{Available Online \\ Available date. XXXX-XX/ \copyright\ All rights reserved.}

\doi{\url{https://www.doi.org/exampledoi/XXXXXXXXXX}}

\institution{Example}

\etal{Author last name et al.}

\footitle{Example}

\course{Example}

%---------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\lipsum[2-10]
\\

\textbf{On the first page the footer is different from the rest of the pages. I would like to implement something that always shows below but automatically adjusts to the lines that are placed in case I have more information.}\\

\textbf{As I placed it now, you can see that the bottom margin is smaller than the top one and I would like them to be the same.}

\newpage

\textbf{Here the footer change. But if you tried to make the footer larger to fit the information for the first page, it no longer looks good because it looks unnaturally large on the other pages.}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}

And this is what I get. As you can see, the bottom part is smaller than the top and, because of the way I made the code, I have to adjust it manually.
What I mean is that I have not come up with a solution that can place information at the bottom of the first page and adjust the desired height by itself.

Could someone give me a solution where a block of information is always placed at the bottom of the first page or how to get the result of the first image. Thank you very much :)

\fancyfoot from fancyhdr is unrelated to footnotes, which are placed in the main text block, page head and foot are fixed regions for page numbers and running heads.

Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example we can compile.

I have already added a code that can be useful as a base, I hope it will help you. Thank you very much.

You need to change the \textheight of the first page. To adjust it automatically, if the height of the footer may change, use a box
\newbox\firstfootbox
\sbox{\firstfootbox}{%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
    \rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
    \footnotesize
    \vskip1.5pt
    \@corres\par
    \@doi\par
    \@footinfo\par
  }%
}

The extra height of the footer corresponds to the box depth (with [t], the \parbox top line is aligned with the baseline). Remove-it from \textheight
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\dp\firstfootbox}

and recall the box content in footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\usebox{\firstfootbox}}

Last thing, you need to restore the geometry of the next pages. You can do it with the hook
\AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{
  \restoregeometry
  \global\textheight=\textheight
}

Since lengths assignments are local, \global\textheight=\textheight is needed (it's the only length changed by \restoregeometry).
I suggest to create a command with all geometry settings
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpagegeometry}{}{%
  \sbox{\firstfootbox}{%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
      \rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
      \footnotesize
      \vskip1.5pt
      \@corres\par
      \@doi\par
      \@footinfo\par
    }%
  }
  \addtolength{\textheight}{-\dp\firstfootbox}
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{
    \restoregeometry
    \global\textheight=\textheight
  }
}

and call it before \maketitle.
Full example:
\begin{filecontents*}{example.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{example}[2024/03/28 Rho LaTeX class]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{extarticle}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[twocolumn]{extarticle}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}

% ---------------------------------------------

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{iflang}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{url}

% ---------------------------------------------

\usepackage[left=1.25cm, right=1.25cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.75cm]{geometry}

% ---------------------------------------------

\newcommand\correspondingauthor[2][]{
  \gdef\@corres{\textsuperscript{#1}\fontsize{6.5}{9}\selectfont#2}
}
\newcommand{\footerfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\institution}[1]{\def\@institution{#1}}
\newcommand{\etal}[1]{\def\@etal{#1}}
\newcommand{\course}[1]{\def\@course{#1}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\def\@doi{#1}}
\newcommand{\footitle}[1]{\def\@footitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\footinfo}[1]{\def\@footinfo{#1}}

% ---------------------------------------------

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newbox\firstfootbox

\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpagegeometry}{}{%
  \sbox{\firstfootbox}{%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
      \rule{3cm}{0.5pt}
      \footnotesize
      \vskip1.5pt
      \@corres\par
      \@doi\par
      \@footinfo\par
    }%
  }
  \addtolength{\textheight}{-\dp\firstfootbox}
  \AddToHookNext{shipout/after}{
    \restoregeometry
    \global\textheight=\textheight
  }
}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
  \fancyhead[R]{}
  \fancyhead[L]{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\usebox{\firstfootbox}}
}

  % Header
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily\footnotesize{\itshape\@title}\hspace{10pt}{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\footnotesize{\bfseries\thepage}\hspace{10pt}{\itshape\@title}}
\fancyhead[LE]{}
\fancyhead[RO]{}

% Footer
\lfoot{}%
\cfoot{}%
\rfoot{}%

\fancyfoot[RO]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@institution\hspace{10pt}{\bfseries\@date}\hspace{10pt}\@footitle}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@etal}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@etal}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\sffamily\footnotesize\@course}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % No footer rule
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twoside]{example}

% ---------------------------------------------

\title{Example}
\author{Author 1}
\date{April 2024}

% ---------------------------------------------
% Using the commands
% ---------------------------------------------

\correspondingauthor[$\ast$]{Corresponding author at: This is an example of how
  you can customize this part of the article. Please, provide the corresponding
  author information and publisher here. \textit{E-mail address:}
  example@organization.com.}

\footinfo{Available Online \\ Available date. XXXX-XX/ \copyright\ All
  rights reserved.}

\doi{\url{https://www.doi.org/exampledoi/XXXXXXXXXX}}

\institution{Example}

\etal{Author last name et al.}

\footitle{Example}

\course{Example}

%---------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\firstpagegeometry

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\lipsum[2-10]
\\

\textbf{On the first page the footer is different from the rest of the pages.
  I would like to implement something that always shows below but automatically
  adjusts to the lines that are placed in case I have more information.}\\

\textbf{As I placed it now, you can see that the bottom margin is smaller than
  the top one and I would like them to be the same.}

\newpage

\textbf{Here the footer change. But if you tried to make the footer larger to
  fit the information for the first page, it no longer looks good because it
  looks unnaturally large on the other pages.}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}



